# VBA - For exporting data from Excel to text (cell by cell with separators)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question with VBA. I'm trying to create macro for exporting my Excel sheet to txt file. > I have a sheet where I have some records and I would like to get them one by one in new line with name of column as separator. It should be like that :

```
"column name1" 

 1value_col1 

"coumn name2"

1value_col2

"column name 1"

2value_col1

"column name2"

2value_col2
```

And etc. till the end of document.

Thank you for any advice examples of something similar.

Comment: Please share your current VBA. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Make another worksheet where you format the data as shown in your example e.g.

```
=Data!A$1
=OFFSET(Data!A1;ROUNDDOWN(ROW()/(no_of_columns*2);0);0)
=Data!A$2
...
```

Or if you want a macro:

```
Dim c As Long
For i = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
   For j = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
      Worksheets("Out").Range("A1").Offset(c).Value = Cells(1, j)
      c = c + 1
      Worksheets("Out").Range("A1").Offset(c).Value = Cells(i, j)
      c = c + 1
   Next j
Next i
```

Then  then simply save the worksheet as txt:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "C:\Book1.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS,CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: ok so what can be a macro for transfer data in this case between sheets ?? There is like 500 records so preparing document like that is quite a lot of time

Comment: No macro - just write some formulas and copy them way down along the worksheet. The formulas will format the data appropriately. Use my example above.

Comment: Use macro above or formulas